# How to cover unselected tab with border in TabBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to cover unselected tab with 1px orange color border on all sides as in the picture.
[image]
here what i done already. i can't do just that border. Thanks for help.

```
List<Tab> tabs = [
     Tab(text: 'Tab1'),
     Tab(text: 'Tab2'),
     Tab(text: 'Tab3'),
     ];
DefaultTabController(
           length: tabs.length,
           child: ListView(
           controller: scrollController,
           children: [
              TabBar(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              tabs: tabs,
              isScrollable: true,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  borderRadius:
                     BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     border: Border.all(
                     color: Colors.orange,)),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.orange,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
```

I tried covering tabs with container and give decoration. but it gives border only text not for hole tab

Comment: sorry for posting code like that. I posted a question first time. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom tab widget with desired decoration for the unselected tab. Something like this:

```
TabBar(
  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
  indicatorWeight: double.minPositive,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
  indicator: selectedTab,
  labelColor: Colors.white,
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.orange,
  tabs: ['Tab1', 'Tab2', 'Tab3']
      .map((tab) => Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 48,
          decoration: unselectedTab,
          child: Center(child: Text(tab))))
      .toList(),
)
```